# How to add bumpiness to a car/roller coaster motion?

Tags: animation

How would one add bumpiness/bounciness to a motion animated in blender. For example, if I were to model a car moving on a road as a POV or a roller coaster from POV. I am currently working on a roller coaster, but I am asking this as a general question, how would one add the random bumpiness to anything moving on the road/tracks ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do this by adding the noise modifier to you animation.

1) Open the property’s tab in the graph editor and select the animation you want to add the bumpiness to
2) Go the modifiers tab and select noise

You can read more about the noise modifier and other fcurve modifiers [here](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/graph_editor/fcurves/modifiers.html)

Note: Don’t add the modifier to the f-curve that controls the direction your object is going. For this particular problem add keyframes to your Y and Z locations of the car (assuming that car is moving along the X direction of the path) and then add noise to f-curves for Y and Z locations.

Comment: Hi, I had to un-answer the question. I finally got a chance to try this out, and this essentially adds noise to the function in the f-curve. Thus, it seems like the car is bouncing forward and backward (along the direction of motion, not other directions). However, I want the car to bounce left/right or up/down as you would expect in a ride. The f-curve modifier adds noise along the path of the curve. Apologize in advance if I missing something here ?

Comment: Since my car is already smoothly travelling on the curve, essentially I need to add random vibration along the other directions (left/right and top/bottom). Then together it would like a bumpy ride. So, how do I add vibration to my car along its local axes.

Comment: Ok figured it out. I keyframed the X and Y location of the camera and added noise to that. I marked it answered again. Will it be possible to edit your answer to mention adding noise to the location f-curve (after key framing) and not the usual f-curve one uses for the travelling. Might be helpful for noobs like me.