# Making many objects move within another object constrained to a function generated pattern with variations

Tags: animation, geometry-nodes

2d animator and Blender newb here.

So, I recently installed this program for a project I'm making, and I would need to animate some object with these factors:

- The object moves only within another object.
- The object has numerous instances that move independently.
- I have control over their number through a slider.
- The objects' movement has a specific pattern that I have control over, not through keyframe animations, but through some kind of
  function, and there are variations between every instance of the
  object

The final project would basically be a human figure made of polygons that move in an erratic pattern within the figure's boundaries; the figure's mesh itself would be hidden, so that the result would be an "Abstract" human being, that I could easily edit with sliders.

I don't really want a full tutorial on this. (I mean, you would do the work for me lmao), but I'd really appreciate some "Vague tips" (like idk, "For point number one try playing with these nodes")

Thanks a bunch in advance!

Comment: You could instance points within the base mesh and then use an fcurve modifier to add noise to the instance locations. - https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/107102/how-to-add-bumpiness-to-a-car-roller-coaster-motion/107107#107107 - I'm not sure how hard this is to implement with something like geometry nodes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you asked for vague tips:

1. You'll need some scripting support, so I suggest "Scripting for Artists" if you're not already familiar with Blender's Python API
2. The controls probably should be a panel in the VIEW3D UI region
3. You might want to investigate blender's *boids* implementation to get a sense of how flocks of objects are controlled in a boid simulation.  (I don't think boids will solve your problem because you seem to want more control over the flight path, but they're a tool that you might copy from.)
4. The hard part is going to be programming the function.  You're basically implementing a physics simulation where you compute the positions of each object from frame to frame.  You might be able to fake this with constrained motion and randomness, instead.
5. Good luck. It sounds like a fun project.

Comment: Thanks a bunch m8! It seems more complicated than i imagined but i'll try getting some help from a friend who knows programming better than me

Comment: Also, thanks for the vagueness haha

Comment: Feel free to ask specific questions as you progress towards your goals.  I really want to see your final render.

Comment: Ok, i'm starting to try something and i think the particle system might be a good start

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cLuDIUbtzYI i managed to make this and it has a lot of the factors i need, but i still need more control over it and well this was the easiest part. I'll update when i get something!

Comment: Ok, i studied for some days and i had an eureka right now as i'm reading again! I just have to put about 10 boids generators with different properties inside of a human mesh with collision!!!!

Comment: I managed to do it!